# Behavior at infinity of an $L^2$ function with $L^2$ mixed second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

If $f$, $\nabla_x \cdot \nabla_y f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d_x\times \mathbb{R}^d_y)$, what can be said about decay at infinity of $\nabla_x f$, $\nabla_y f$?

It is clear that $(\nabla_x^2 + \nabla_y^2) f \in L^2_{x,y}$ implies $\nabla_x, \nabla_y f \in L^2_{x,y}$ (see e.g. "[Is a function in $L^2$ which second derivative is in $L^2$ in $H^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803299/343293) or "[Does existence of the second weak derivative of $f\in L^2$ imply existence of the first?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1825775/343293) Qs&As).

Note that in this setting I only claim control over the mixed second derivative $\nabla_x \cdot\nabla_y f $.

By considering Fourier transforms, we see that we have no control over $\int (|\xi|^2+|\eta|^2) |\widehat{f}(\xi,\eta)|^2d\xi d\eta$ if we only have control over $\int (1+|\xi|^2|\eta|^2) |\widehat{f}(\xi,\eta)|^2d\xi d\eta$. Therefore $\nabla_x f,\nabla_y f$ will not lie in $L^2$ in general.

Do we still obtain useful information about the behavior of $\nabla_x f$ and $\nabla_y f$ at infinity?

For instance, is there enough decay for $\nabla_x f, \nabla_y f$ at infinity such that

$$\int \overline{f} \nabla_x \cdot \nabla_y f = \int  f \nabla_x \cdot \nabla_y \overline{f}$$

Note that I have asked [this question on math.stackexchange before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4803650/343293).

Comment: Well, any function depending on $x$ only will have $f_{xy} = 0$. More generally, $f_{xy} = 0$ is a wave equation up to changing variables (in 1 + 1D), so any entire solution to a wave equation must satisfy any estimate you might construct.

Comment: The last identity you ask for is true, by taking the Fourier transform. You do not need to integrate by parts.

Comment: @user378654 $f$ depends on $x$ and $y$, or am I misinterpreting you?